# How to delete a point in influxDB

Tags: python, influxdb

Sorry this is almost certainly a duplicate but I'm just not able to put the informations together.

How do I delete a point from influxDB?
First I use Python and the `DataFrameClient`:

```
client = DataFrameClient('localhost', '8086', 'root', 'root', 'meteo')
```

Then I write multiple points like:

```
meta = pd.DataFrame({'path': ['A'],
                     'table': ['B'],
                     'md5': ['C']},
                     index=[pd.datetime.now()])
client.write_points(dataframe=meta,
                    measurement='__SRC__',
                    protocol='line',
                    database='meteo')
```

Now I would like to delete all points, where `path` is `'A'`. My attempt using `client.query`:

```
DELETE FROM "meteo"."autogen"."__SRC__" WHERE path='A'

> received status code 400 from server: err: error parsing query:
>     retention policy not supported at line 1, char 1
```

Now this message has probably a meaning, but could you help me on what I'm doing wrong and where to read about it? Thank you a lot!

### Update

Following the answer of @JanGaraj, I have some more results. The following query (I have a var. `table` instead of `path` but wouldn't see how this makes a difference.)

```
client = influxdb.DataFrameClient('localhost', '8086', 'root', 'root', 'meteo')
client.query('DELETE  FROM "__SRC__" WHERE table=\'A\'')
```

returns

```
ResultSet({})
```

but does not delete anything (with `SELECT * FROM "__SRC__" WHERE table=\'A\'` i get 4 datapoints).

The same query (`DELETE  FROM "__SRC__" WHERE table='A'`) put into Chronograf gives "database not found:", which makes sense but I wouldn't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, by `DELETE` specification, you, effectively, can't delete a single point - you delete all points in a series.

In practice, in this case, you can consider that tags make a series (oversimplification, but that works here).

And tags are what `DELETE` takes to define a series to be affected - never values!

In other words, you can specify **ONLY** tags in your `WHERE`.

Now, what I get from this Py library doc(-), that `DataFrame` is considered as set of values, **NOT** tags.

And that is exactly why it does not work: you should put your `path` (and most likely, `table` too, consider the cardinality here) into the tags (separate parameter in your call), NOT values.

Then it's gonna work, but the question is - why would you *need* to delete the points at all?
Could you answer this question?

*-) The thing is truly disgusting, I must admit, don't know how you guys manage to stand it & not run away immediately to some more humanely designed & DOCUMENTED libs & languages*

Comment: Thank you a lot for the explanation!
I probably wouldn't not want to delete points once I understand how influx works. So I read in several files and store the values in the database (as timeseries). Alongside I have to store - and update - meta-data for the files, like the md5 checksum, so that I can skip unchanged files in the next run. How should I save this meta data? I mean it's not really time-series data... Basically I'd just need a lookup "file path --> md5-sum" but I thought it might be convenient if I try to save all data into the sam DB. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try query:

```
DELETE FROM "__SRC__" WHERE path='A'
```

DB and retention policy is not supported in the FROM part in this case - see [InfluxDB DELETE doc](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/query_language/database_management/#delete-series-with-delete).

Comment: So does that mean I cannot use the same query from Python and directly, say in Chronograf?

Comment: Why you can't use it? Use right syntax and you can use everywhere.

Comment: There I get "database not found". Makes sense since I never specify it anywhere but apparently it's not allowed to specify it in the command?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify time range with vary close range. For example 1 microsecond

```
delete from "rs_5f5b34f89aded07f6dba81e0" where time >=1599858000000000000 and time < 1599858000000000001
```

Comment: I don't think this answer is relevant to the question...

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the actual query string, you're missing one big component here - when using the InfluxDB client, you need to specify the method to be POST, as it defaults to GET for querying the database and getting the points back - which is why your query returns a ResultSet and does not delete the points. So, you need to use:

```
client.query(query_str, method="POST")
```

You can take a look at the [InfluxDB client implementation](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python/blob/master/influxdb/client.py#L782) for some examples.